# Как добавить сервисы Google в Android Studio, чтобы уменшить размер

Tags: android, service

Ребята хочу добавить AdMob, но не используя

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
Так  как из за этой команды вес приложение возрастает в 5 раз.
До этого весил 700кб, сейчас 5 мегабайт, Это слишком! Есть ли выход? Читал что какой то можно ProGuard задействовать или в Gradle указать чисто для AdMob

Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


    android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.eranewgames.animevideo"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

repositories{
    flatDir{
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'
    compile 'cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.4.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}
```

Comment: что конкретно вы используете в из сервисов?

Comment: включить прогуард, который вырежет неиспользуемые части Google Play Services

Comment: @metalurgus, можете написать как это сделать в ответе?

Comment: `minifyEnabled false` для начала изменить на `minifyEnabled true`. Дальше - если возникнут какие-то ошибки, исправить их.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно подключить отдельно только необходимую часть, полный список тут:

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Для AdMob достаточно `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0`

Comment: И на сколько размер уменшится?

Comment: Вот вы нам и скажите :)

Comment: Ну было 4 метра стало где - то 2.40. Ну лучше все же))

Comment: На всякий случай напомню что AdMob не единственный провайдер рекламы в андроид.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно, перед созданием проекта в Android Studio, Вам должны предложить компоненты которые Вы хотите использовать в проекте. Начиная `Play Games API`, заканчивая `Google Cast API`.

Попробуйте создать новый проект и вставить туда тот же код, но уже с выбранными компонентами.